# Extent of `as` in pattern matching

Tags: pattern-matching, ocaml

Given a function that removes consecutive duplicates from a list

```
let rec compress l =
  match l with
  | [] -> []
  | [x] -> [x]
  | x :: (y :: _ as t) -> if x = y then compress t else x :: compress t;;
```

yields the correct result

```
compress ["a"; "a";"b";"c";"c"] ;;
- : string list = ["a"; "b"; "c"]
```

but if instead of `x :: (y :: _ as t)` I change to `x :: (y :: t)`, then I get the incorrect result

```
compress ["a"; "a";"b";"c";"c"] ;;
- : string list = ["b"; "c"]
```

---

What is going on here ? I can't wrap my head around as to how the declaration `_ as t` changes the output of the function. Intuitively, I would think they are equivalent statements (`:: _ as t` and `:: t`), but seemingly they are not.

Could someone elaborate ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are not equivalent since [as](https://ocaml.org/manual/patterns.html#sss:pat-alias) stretches as far as possible to the left, so in

```
x :: (y :: ys as t)
```

the variable `t` is bound to `y::ys` not just `ys`

Comment: I’ll mention that this applies in particular to another particularly confusing use of `as`: in `(x, y as pair)`, the variable `pair` is not bound to just `y` but rather to the pair `(x, y)` (in which the parens are in fact optional, according to OCaml syntax). This sometimes occurs in function definitions.